# React app cannot find my tests "No tests found"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs

I am new to the react (Jest) tests and I wanted to start practice but for some reason I get an error that there are no tests found.

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "client",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.5",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.4.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.1",
    "socket.io-client": "^4.5.2",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test --watchAll",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

my test

```
import {render, screen, cleanup} from '@testing-library/react';
import Home from '../src/Home.js';

test('test', () => {
    expect(true).toBe(true);
})
```

the test is located in another folder called *testing* inside the src folder (where the original jsx file is). I am trying to run it with npm test but it never finds any tests. The main file is Home.js and the test file is called Home.test.js

Comment: How is your test file named?

Comment: The main file is Home.js and the test file is called Home.test.js

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hope this help**

From [create-react-app docs](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/running-tests/):

> Jest will look for test files with any of the following popular naming conventions:
> Files with `.js` suffix in `__tests__` folders.
> Files with `.test.js` suffix.
> Files with `.spec.js` suffix.
> The `.test.js` / `.spec.js` files (or the `__tests__` folders) can be located at any depth under the `src` top level folder.

Answer (score 0):

You need to name your file with mytest.test.jsx

Comment: The main file is Home.js and the test file is called Home.test.js